# How to handleChange a TextInput component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have make this TextInput component

```
export const TextInput = (props) => {
  const { label } = props
  return (
    <div className="field text">
      <input type="text" />
      <label>{label}</label>
    </div>
  )
}
```

But at the call of this component, I would like to handleChange each input according to its name

```
handleChange = (e) => this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value })


<TextInput
   label="Email"
   name="email"
   value={this.state.email}
   onChange={this.handleChange}
/>
```

The problem is that my state and my method are not in the component.

I have to pass my method in props?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you should create `TextInput` like this:

```
export const TextInput = (props) => {
  const { 
     name,
     label,
     value,
     onChange,
     disabled,
     customClass,
      ...others
  } = props
  return (
    <div className="field text">
      <input 
         className={customClass}
         name={name}
         type="text"
         disabled={disabled}
         value={value}
         onChange={e => onChange(e)} // I will return event here, not currenTarget.value
         {...others}
      />
      <label>{label}</label>
    </div>
  )
}
```

And then, you can use `TextInput` as an `input element` like this:

```
<TextInput
   label="Email"
   customClass="class-custom-input"
   disabled={false}
   name="email"
   value={this.state.email}
   onChange={this.handleChange} // at here you can received an `event`
   onClick={...} // will be pass as ...others in TextInput
   onBlur={...} // will be pass as ...others in TextInput
/>
```

Comment: I have make the same code and my handleChange method responds to me "Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"

Comment: You can see again my edit. I will return event of `onChange` in `TextInput`, not `currenTarget.value`

Answer (score 2):

> The problem is that my state and my method are not in the component.

It's actually not a problem. You are doing the right thing.

It's what React calls as [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html).

So just use the `props` in your child component.

```
export const TextInput = (props) => {
  const { label } = props
  return (
    <div className="field text">
       // use props
      <input type="text"
        onChange={props.onChange}
        name={props.name}
        value={props.value}
      />
      <label>{label}</label>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the onChange to the child component

```
export const TextInput = (props) => {
  const { label } = props
  return (
    <div className="field text">
      <input onChange={props.onChange} type="text" />
      <label>{label}</label>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: This is not a class component, `this` won't work. Also no need to wrap `onChange` prop in a function.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable the onChange handler on `input` first:

```
export const TextInput = (props) => {
  const { label } = props
  return (
    <div className="field text">
      <input type="text" onChange={props.onChange}/>
      <label>{label}</label>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the useRef hook and pass it to the TextInput component.

```
const emailRef = useRef(null)

handleChange = () => this.setState({ [emailRef.current.name]: emailRef.current.value })


<TextInput
   label="Email"
   name="email"
   value={this.state.email}
   onChange={this.handleChange}
   ref={emailRef}
/>
```